# Unable to print multiple copies

Tags: printing

I have a HP4000 printer that I just added a network card to and now I can not print multiple copies with it.  My OS is Windows 7 (64 bit).  I am using a PCL5 print driver.  anyone have any ideas of how I might be fix this.

Comment: I just found a fix.  I changed the driver from a PCL5 to a PCL6 and it seems to have solved the problem.  Go figure.

Comment: Please put that as an answer and accept it to show that it's been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the driver from a PCL5 to a PCL6 and it seems to have solved the problem.

(From comment by OP.)